# Ionic form Validation using Components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-forms

I am trying to do the form validation in Ionic using components. Below is the code I've done so far.. I have created component and I am calling it in **contact.html** page here `<my-text>` is the component, I need to validate what user inputs in the component in **contact.ts** file, the problem I am getting here is how can I fetch the data user enters in component in **contact.ts** file. Please let me know if you need more info on this. Thanks..

contact.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="ContactForm">

        <div class="topp2" padding>
        <my-text ttx="Name" placeholder="Please enter your name" formControlname="name" (keyup)="validateSubmitButton()" [class.invalid]="!ContactForm.controls.name.valid && (ContactForm.controls.name.dirty || submitAttempt)"></my-text>
        <ion-item *ngIf="!ContactForm.controls.name.valid  && (ContactForm.controls.name.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                        <p class="errorMsg">Please enter a valid name.</p>
        </ion-item>
        </div>

     <div class="topp2" padding>
     <my-text ttx="Email" placeholder="Please enter your email" formControlname="email" (keyup)="validateSubmitButton()" [class.invalid]="!ContactForm.controls.email.valid && (ContactForm.controls.email.dirty || submitAttempt)"></my-text>
     <ion-item *ngIf="!ContactForm.controls.email.valid  && (ContactForm.controls.email.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <p class="errorMsg">Please enter a valid Email.</p>
            </ion-item>
    </div>

    </form>
```

contact.ts

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
        import { MyBtnComponent } from '../../components/my-btn/my-btn';
        import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
        /**
         * Generated class for the Contact page.
         *
         * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
         * Ionic pages and navigation.
         */

        @IonicPage()
        @Component({
          selector: 'page-contact',
          templateUrl: 'contact.html',
        })
        export class ContactPage {

          ContactForm:FormGroup;
          myBtnText: any = "Submit";
          submitAttempt: boolean = false;
          isenabled:boolean = false;

          constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

               this.ContactForm = formBuilder.group({
                name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z .]*'), Validators.required])],
             email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'),Validators.required]) ],
    });
    }

  validateSubmitButton(){
    console.log('inside validate submit function');
    console.log('is name valid? :'+this.ContactForm.controls.name.value);

  this.isenabled = this.ContactForm.controls.name.valid && this.ContactForm.controls.email.valid 
  console.log('Is enabled in validate submit btn is:'+this.isenabled);

  }
}
```

my-text.html (Component)

```
<!-- Generated template for the MyTextComponent component -->
<div class="mytxt">
<ion-item no-lines >    
  <ion-input type="text"  [placeholder]="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</div>
```

my-text.ts

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the MyTextComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
 * Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'my-text',
  templateUrl: 'my-text.html'
})
export class MyTextComponent {

  text: string;
  @Input("ttx") plcToUse;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello MyTextComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World!';
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.text = this.plcToUse;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to use MyTextComponent as a formcontrol.. is that your question?

Comment: your component needs to implement ControlValueAccessor Interface to be used as a formControl. Check https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83 blog or google search others